# Is there any way to create Pdf in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pdf-generation

I am working a win phone app where I want to create pdf in offline mode. I am ready to purchase a product if available.

Comment: Please share your code/research. Else they will keep voting down or close your question

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of free (and commercial) libraries, for example:

- [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharpwp7.codeplex.com/)
- [iTextSharp](http://itextsharpsl.codeplex.com/)

---

EDIT:
As @AdielYaacov noted, this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx) mentions that those libraries doesn't work on Windows Phone. Please check the reasons for each library and look at an alternative in the link.

Comment: As far as i know pdfsharp (as is) and itextsharp  don't work on windows phone apps. check out this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx

Comment: Post edited to include incompatibility reasons on previous libraries and alternative, thanks to @AdielYaacov comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use http://pdfsharpwp7.codeplex.com/. a library intended for wp7.